# Determine Start date and End Date from list of days of a Product transaction in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have case where i have to find the start date and end date of a Product

I have a table as below,

```
Product Country     Attribute_1     Attribute_2     Attribute_3     Transaction_date
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130101
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130102
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130103
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130104
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130105
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130201
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130202
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130203
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130204
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130205
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130301
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130302
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130303
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20140101
```

Output should be,

```
Product Country     Attribute_1     Attribute_2     Attribute_3     Start_Date      End_Date
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130101        20130201
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130201                    20130301
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130301        99999999
```

Here unique key is PRODUCT + COUNTRY

I tried MIN, MAX and FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE as below, but not able to get the desired result.

`FIRST_VALUE(Transaction_date) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT, COUNTRY OVER Attrubute1, Attribute_2, Attribute_3 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Tried out Min, Max and Groupby, it doesn't give the desired result. The output is

```
Product     Country     Attribute_1     Attribute_2     Attribute_3     Start_Date      End_Date
ABC         US          Color           Green           Small           20130101        20140101
ABC         US          Color           Red             Big             20130201        20130205
```

In this case, if i pass the date as 20130204, i would get two records. Ideally i should get only the second record.

Can someone please help me to get the desired result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use Postgres, even Oracle would work. I have data reside in both and i prefer code in Postgres. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
lag(coalesce(Attribute_1,'')||'|'
    ||coalesce(Attribute_1,'')||'|'
    ||coalesce(Attribute_1,'')) as la 
over (partition by Product, Country order by Transaction_date)
```

to get attributes of a previous row.

Filter out all rows that have same attributes for current and previous rows. This will give you 3 rows as in the desired output.

From this point it should be trivial to build the rest of the query.